# How can I inject a dependency quickly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

While I was coding on an ASP.NET Core project, and I need some service in my action, like `_tokenManager`, I have to add a new dependency injection, like this:

[image: vs-injection]

Adding a new dependency for a controller takes me at least 3 lines of code so it was not easy. When I need several dependencies it will cost me lots of time.

BTW, while I was changing my code, some dependency may not be necessary and shall be removed. I have to check those dependencies one by one to make sure each of then is necessary. So is there any easy way to automatically add those dependencies when I try to use them and suggest me to remove those not necessary?

It seems that Visual Studio already has this feature. How to enable this feature?

Comment: How any tool in universe can find all run-time dependencies at design-time, or find out, that particular IFoo isn't required at run-time anymore?

Comment: @vasily.sib In TypeScript, DI only requires one line of code. I guess there may be easier way or some shortcut to inject one instead of typing 3 f**king lines.

Comment: @Anduin, can you show me how do you DI in TypeScript with 1 line?

Comment: @vasily.sib  https://github.com/AiursoftWeb/Kahla.App/blob/dev/src/app/Controllers/talking.component.ts#L50

Comment: @Anduin, there is also 3 lines [here](https://github.com/AiursoftWeb/Kahla.App/blob/dev/src/app/Services/MessageService.ts#L24). Anyway, the only reason why this work for TypeScript - JavaScript is loosely typed, C# is strongly typed

Comment: @vasily.sib  While I was watching Microsoft expert writting code and they just injected a dependency in a second. It seems that they have some shortcut or quick way. So is it?

Comment: @Anduin it's `Ctrl` + `.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got a solution.

If you write your injected dependency first, like this:

```cs
public class MyController
{
    private readonly MyDependency instance <Ctrl + . here>
    public MyController()
    {
    }
}
```

Visual Studio won't give you suggestion to complete this.

But if you write your dependency in your constructor first like this:

```cs
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(
         MyDependency instance <Ctrl + . here>
        )
    {
    }
}
```

[image: vs]

And Visual Studio 2019 will help you complete it.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `.` is very useful, try it in other situations as well

Comment: @vasily.sib I understand that `Ctrl + .` can apply some Visual Studio suggestion but I was struggling on the first attempt the answer mentioned. Until I asked Microsoft Official did I find the correct way to complete dependency injection quickly. BTW, thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Any idea how to prevent visual studio from prefixing the initialization in the ctor with `this.`?